# Import C# dll's dotted name files in IronPython problems

Tags: import, assemblies, ironpython

I've been trying to import two C # .dll using IronPython. One is called m1.sdk.dll the other is called m1.sdk.something.dll. But I got error. The error message says it could not find a type in m1.sdk.something.dll.

But they are loaded through clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath () and import of IronPython. I see them carried through clr.References

Is there a way to load these .dll's so despite the name dotted IronPython see how the same module?

```
import clr

clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("c:\\path_to_file_\\m1.sdk.dll")
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath("c:\\path_to_file_\\m1.sdk.something.dll")

import m1.sdk
import m1.sdk.something     # The error occurs here
```

*Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

ImportError: No module named something*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkSHJ.png)

Comment: Please add your code as well as exact exceptions/stacks.

Comment: I think the python understand that they are the same module but are not, it is to attach a module in the other run-time?

Comment: Have you verified that both `m1.sdk.dll` and `m1.sdk.something.dll` actually contains objects in the namespaces `m1.sdk` and `m1.sdk.something`? You're importing namespaces, not assemblies. There is no requirement that an assembly needs to define namespaces that match the assembly file name.

Comment: I added some prints to help understand.

Comment: I use Win7-64bit, Ironpython console 32bits and .dll's are 32bits too.

Comment: I was looking at the manifest. An assembly needs another with log4net name. I do not have it.  How did you and Simon said.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is most likely not related to the name or similarity of the two referenced assemblies.
`No module named something` will occur if there are no public/visible types found withing the namespace `m1.sdk.something`.

Comment: Thank you Simon, I will check the file that I have here.